# ASP.NET Core Identity: Multiple providers for the same account

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I've been trying to wrap my head around the new ASP.NET Core Identity framework.

I want to be able to allow customers to sign-in using external providers so I do not have to worry about password storage.  That works if I use the default provider: `.AddDefaultIdentity<EntityUser>()`, along with `.AddAuthentication` (with `AddFacebook`, `AddGoogle`, `AddMicrosoftAccount`).

Some people have a Google account *and* a Facebook account.  I would like to allow users to login to their account, and then add additional providers to the same user (so long as the e-mails match).

The Identity Framework portion of AspNetCore seems to tightly control everything.  I know how to override the views, but not how to override control-flow.  How can I dip my own logic into its processes to coerce login, registration?  I would also like to forward a user to the external providers when the user is **already logged in**.

All I need is a direction, they've separated concerns so much with the new AspNetCore that it's akin to an onion.  This makes it difficult to know where what you want is.  I don't even know what I don't know to get started.

Comment: afaik it already works the way you want, users can add any providers you've configured from the manage controller, the option for the user to add social auth should be there for any providers you have configured. it does not verify that the email is the same at the provider and that doesn't really matter since the user can only add it by signing into the provider then you know it is the users social account. not all social providers return an email but in any case if the user already has an account on your site with an email, signing in via a social provider won't change the users email.

Comment: I shouldn't have said managecontroller, once upon a time it was a controller but now it is razorpages. you can see the external logins view [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/Account/Manage/ExternalLogins.cshtml)

Comment: It totally didn't register when I was setting this up, but if you go to:
~/Identity/Account/Manage/ExternalLogins

It does exactly as I wanted.

Their initial sample app sets up something called OpenIdConnect, with an Account controller.  I added in the remaining on my own.  This separate controller instead of the Identity framework is where the concepts seemed to clash.

@JoeAudette, please post a combination of your original message with the Uri to the account management and I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It already works the way you want, users can add any providers you've configured from the  page at ~/Identity/Account/Manage/ExternalLogins

You can see the [source code of the ExternalLogins razor page](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/Account/Manage/ExternalLogins.cshtml) has logic which will show options for the user to add social auth to their existing account.